# How to determine the chosen activity from an intentchooser android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to determine which intent the user selects from my custom intent chooser, but for whatever reason I can't get onReceive to fire. Here's a sample of my code:

```
val extraIntents = intentList.toTypedArray()
val receiver = Intent(context, broadcastReceiver.javaClass)
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,                    
                                   receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
Intent.createChooser(intentList[0], "choose an intent..", 
                     pendingIntent.intentSender)
startActivityForResult(openInChooser, SELECTOR_CODE)
```

And earlier, I defined the broadcastReceiver:

```
broadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

I ran this code and set a break code on that `onReceive` method but it was never triggered. Any help would be greaatly appreciated!

Comment: You're registering it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you can't set the Intent target to an anonymous BroadcastReceiver, or an inner BroadcastReceiver.

Make it a static sub-class or put it in its own file. You can still construct and register it dynamically. (Sidenote: remember to actually register it. It won't receive Intents if it's not registered.)

Alternatively, use a custom action and don't bother with the explicit target component. Dynamically registered BroadcastReceivers aren't subject to the implicit broadcast limitations in Oreo.